# What am i doing wrong with this

Tags: java

```
var target = System.currentTimeMillis() + 7500;

while (true) {
   System.out.println(calculatePercentage(System.currentTimeMillis(), target));
}
```

```
public static long calculatePercentage(final long current, final long max) {
    return current * 100 / max;
}
```

When i run this code it show always 99 while it should get lower by time until 7.5 second pass and show 0 (cause the difference is 0)

What i'm trying to do is the following. I want to display a loading bar for an auction and show the remaining. So the target is the "expiration". Any ideas?

Comment: But is not Integer. It's Long.

Comment: you math is wrong. Consider what happens at the first iteration: you operation is `1.6*10^12 * 100 / (1.6*10^12+7500)`. That's basically almost 100. Your operation at the first iteration should be `0 * 100 / 7500`, and at the last iteration `7500 * 100 / 7500` (or vice-versa, depending on what exactly you're trying to acheive)

Comment: So the calculatePercentage need to be changed

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    waitSeconds(7.5);
}

public static void waitSeconds(double seconds) {
    long mills = (long)(seconds * 1000);
    long startMills = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while (true) {
        int passMills = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() - startMills);
        /*
         * mills     = 100 %
         * passMills = X %
         */
        int percent = (int)((passMills * 100) / mills);

        System.out.println(percent);

        if (percent >= 100)
            break;
    }
}
```